# When the data insert into event table, get user data using user without refreshing

Tags: php, sql, triggers, biometrics

I have a biometric reader that authenticates users. Once authenticated, an access granted event together with the ID of the user is registered in the events table in SQL database. I have placed the reader in a canteen and want to print a meal ticket immediately a user is authenticated. For this, I have connected a printer to a PC near the reader.

I DO LIKE THIS BUT IT NOT FULFILL MY REQUIREMENT

```
<?php 
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finger");
         

       $sql = "CREATE TRIGGER `ersdmmmmecv` AFTER INSERT ON `event` FOR EACH ROW  SELECT fname,Lname INTO @f,@l  FROM user WHERE id=NEW.id;"
       
             $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
           
                       if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                          {  
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                               { 
                                  if(isset($_POST['row']))
                                      {
                    $print_output= $_POST['result'];
                    }
                    try
                    {
                     $fp=pfsockopen("192.168.1.33", 9100);
                         fputs($fp, $print_output);
                         fclose($fp);

                     echo 'Successfully Printed';

                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                    }

                               }
                          }
         $sql2= "DROP TRIGGER ersdmmmmecv";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2); 

?>
```

Comment: where i want to do this

Comment: no I want  database triggering and display data

Comment: How can a database trigger the front end?

Comment: I want do in backend with php and my sql  I want to get a data to display it in front end using others

Comment: I find it odd to create a table trigger only to delete it after creation? (nevermind the race condition by other requests that try to create a trigger that already exists, which will error, since the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement is missing an `IF NOT EXISTS` clause). Anyway, what I'd do instead, is add the `AFTER INSERT` trigger that you have now to the `event` table ONCE, but then have a CRON job to read the `events` table every minute to print new entries. After successful print, then delete the entry just printed. (hope this makes sense?) We have similar handling with FedEx label print jobs.

Comment: it is important for my device